# When does there exist a diffeomorphism between geodesics of distinct derivative operators?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, diffeomorphism

Let $M$ be a smooth, connected manifold, and let $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ be two covariant derivate operators on $M$ such that $\nabla \neq \nabla'$. As we know, a derivative operator $\nabla$ is defined by its set of geodesics, $\Gamma_\nabla = \{ \gamma\;|\;\xi^n\nabla_n\xi^a = 0 \}$, where $\xi$ is the tangent vector field of $\gamma$.

**Under what conditions does there exist a diffeomorphism from $M$ to itself that maps geodesics to geodesics?** Put differently, when does there exist a $d: M \to M$ such that $d^*\Gamma_\nabla = \Gamma_{\nabla'}$, where $d^*\Gamma_\nabla = \{ \gamma\;|\;d^{-1} \circ \gamma \in \Gamma_\nabla \}$.

When there exists such a diffeomorphism, is there a way to construct it explicitly? Note that for any two derivative operators $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$, there exists a smooth symmetric tensor field $C^a_{bc}$ such that

\begin{equation}
(\nabla'_m - \nabla_m)\alpha^{a_1...a_r}_{b1...b_s} = \alpha^{a_1...a_r}_{n...b_s} C^n_{mb_1} + ... + \alpha^{a_1...a_r}_{b_1...n} C^n_{mb_s} - \alpha^{n...a_r}_{b_1...b_s}C^{a_1}_{mn} - ... - \alpha^{a_1...n}_{b_1...b_s}C^{a_r}_{mn}
\end{equation}

So more specifically, supposing that $C^a_{bc}$ is known can we express the sought after diffeomorphism in terms of it?

Comment: Be careful, given any $\nabla$ there is a torsion-free $\nabla^0$ such that $\Gamma_{\nabla} = \Gamma_{\nabla^0}$.

Comment: Thanks Ivo! I'm not sure how that relates to the question, could you please explain?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I'm saying that "a covariant derivative is defined by it's set of geodesics" is not quite true, there's some care that needs to be taken with this.

Comment: OK, I see. I am happy to restrict to torsion-free derivatives for the purposes of this question.